# Methods in dynamodb-cross-region-library are undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, amazon-dynamodb

**Steps to reproduce problem:**

> Clone repo at https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library
>
> Next mvn install inside directory
>
> All my JAVAJDK, PATH, etc. are up to date and I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I've tried with both Eclipse and VSCode

**Problem:**

> After mvn install open file CommandLineInterface.java

```
Line 69, 73 - "log cannot be resolved";
Line 120, 121 - "The method getSourceEndpoint() is undefined for the type 
CommandLineArgs"
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because the `CommandLineArgs.java` class does not have a method named `getSourceEndpoint()`.

The method was removed in the last commit on the 22nd April:
https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library/commit/d755135d7b9898c1e9007e542cd2e518ed1c596a

To fix it you could simply re-add the following back into `CommandLineArgs.java`:

```
public String getSourceEndpoint() {
    return sourceEndpoint;
}
```

**However it looks like it was removed for a good reason to migrate to a new method? So it may pay to open an [issue on github](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library/issues) if you are not sure.**

Comment: @kpuro that means that Log4j is proberbly not in your classpath/library folder (does Maven give any errors or warnings when you instal/package it? Especially a message about Log4j?). See here for some info of Log4j, and how the `@Log4j` annotation works: https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/log4j/Log4j.html

Comment: Alternately you could just remove lines 69 and 73 from CommandLineInterface.java, but it is normally not a good solution.